# Hibernate Criteria DetachedCriteria and Subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

```
DetachedCriteria cr = DetachedCriteria.forClass(DealerSales.class).setProjection(Property.forName("dealerCode"));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("countryCode",01));

Criteria cr1 = session.createCriteria(BrandModelSales.class).add(Subqueries.propertyIn("dealerCode",cr));
```

Below is the exception which am getting:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Scoreboard] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

where `dealecode` is stored as number in table and detachedcriteria is returning it as `String`
`cast()` method is also not working.....
Is thr any another ways to do it except HQL and native query?

Comment: Could you add the mapping info of `countryCode` ?

Comment: Country code mapping is String

Comment: it is a `String`, but in the code shown, it seems you are using an int (`01`). The error message is `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String` Could there be a link ?

Comment: Thanks... Its working now